# Problem with running "EMF Refactor" refactorings on "Modisco" java model

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, modeling, emf

I wanna run **EMF Refactor** Ecore refactorings on my **Modisco** java model.

EMF Refactor has said:

> EMF Refactor can be used for refactorings of any models whose meta
>   model is based on EMF Ecore.

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/modeling.emft.refactor

Modisco java models have these conditions ?! right?

so I have some trouble with using prepared EMF Refactor Ecore refactoring techniques on the modisco (.xmi) java model.
here the list of EMF Refactor techniques :
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Techniques

and I think EMF Refactor just supports (.ecore) model files and the modisco java model have a different structure that is not exactly the same as the Ecore model.
If this is true, is there any way to turning the modisco java model (.xmi) to Ecore model (.ecore) that is suitable for EMF Refactor?
or maybe Adapt the EMF Refactor Techniques to Modisco Java model ?

is it possible?

---

My used tools:

- Eclipse Modeling tools (Photon)
- MoDisco SDK (1.2.0)
- EMF Refactor (0.9.0)
- JRE 1.8.0_202